# In LINQ, select all values of property X where X != null

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a shorter way to write the following? (Something that would check for null without explicitly writing `!= null`)

```
from item in list 
where item.MyProperty != null 
select item.MyProperty
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want the code to be explicit about what it does?

Comment: I am not aware of any shorter way. But even your version is what is generally considered "long".

Comment: That is pretty simple.  But, if an individual item in the list is null you will get a NRE.  Your where clause needs to be item != null && item.MyProperty != null.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes For nullable value type and newly added nullable reference type, null-checked-then-select still gives you a nullable type.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use the [`OfType` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx). It ignores null values in the source sequence. Just use the same type as `MyProperty` and it won't filter out anything else.

```
// given:
// public T MyProperty { get; }
var nonNullItems = list.Select(x => x.MyProperty).OfType<T>();
```

I would advise against this though. If you want to pick non-null values, what can be more explicit than saying you want "the MyProperties from the list that are not null"?

Comment: I will listen to everybody's advice and leave it as it is. But I marked your answer as accepted because you told me something I didn't know.

Comment: I like this one - it keeps the code as clean as possible, so long as you can remember how OfType<T> functions! Otherwise, I would go with @CodeInChaos's second extension method.

Comment: Abusing `OfType` as a null check is unintuitive and bad style.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Not really. For nullable value type and newly added nullable reference type, null-checked-then-select still gives you a nullable type.

Comment: readability: 0, added more confusion.

Answer (score 57):

You could define your own extension method, but I wouldn't recommend that.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectNonNull<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence,Func<T, TResult> projection)
{
   return sequence.Select(projection).Where(e => e != null);
}
```

I don't like this one because it mixes two concerns. Projecting with `Select` and filtering your null values are separate operations and should not be combined into one method.

---

I'd rather define an extension method that only checks if the item isn't null:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereNotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
   return sequence.Where(e => e != null);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> WhereNotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> sequence)
    where T : struct
{
   return sequence.Where(e => e != null).Select(e => e.Value);
}
```

This has only a single purpose, checking for null. For nullable value types it converts to the non nullable equivalent, since it's useless to preserve the nullable wrapper for values which cannot be null.

With this method, your code becomes:

```
list.Select(item => item.MyProperty).WhereNotNull()
```

Comment: Except it does not work if the expression tree is needed (eg in entity framework)

Comment: @RicoSuter If you need to support that, add an overload of `IQueryable<T>`.

Answer (score 16):

I tend to create a static class containing basic functions for cases like these. They allow me write expressions like

```
var myValues myItems.Select(x => x.Value).Where(Predicates.IsNotNull);
```

And the collection of predicate functions:

```
public static class Predicates
{
    public static bool IsNull<T>(T value) where T : class
    {
        return value == null;
    }

    public static bool IsNotNull<T>(T value) where T : class
    {
        return value != null;
    }

    public static bool IsNull<T>(T? nullableValue) where T : struct
    {
        return !nullableValue.HasValue;
    }

    public static bool IsNotNull<T>(T? nullableValue) where T : struct
    {
        return nullableValue.HasValue;
    }

    public static bool HasValue<T>(T? nullableValue) where T : struct
    {
        return nullableValue.HasValue;
    }

    public static bool HasNoValue<T>(T? nullableValue) where T : struct
    {
        return !nullableValue.HasValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: In using this method, I've renamed the class to `Is` and removed the `Is` prefix from all methods. It makes things more readable IMO: `collection.Where(Is.NotNull).Select...`

Comment: Just glad I was able to help someone out!

Comment: Better not use operators == and != for generic  types. Because they maybe  ovveriden in type.
Use ReferenceEquals(value, null)

Comment: @HorevIvan That assumes you don't want to respect the `operator ==` logic in the generic type. I would argue it is up to the author of the generic type to ensure what it means for `==` equality.

Comment: @HorevIvan You cannot override `==`, you can only overload it. But the overloading does not affect generic type parameters.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to skip a check if it exists.

Answer (score 4):

// if you need to check if all items' MyProperty doesn't have null

```
if (list.All(x => x.MyProperty != null))
// do something
```

// or if you need to check if at least one items' property has doesn't have null

```
if (list.Any(x => x.MyProperty != null))
// do something
```

But you always have to check for null

Comment: This for me is the correct answer.  Maybe my requirements were different than the person asking the question, but this worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 3):

get one column in the distinct select and ignore null values:

```
 var items = db.table.Where(p => p.id!=null).GroupBy(p => p.id)
                                .Select(grp => grp.First().id)
                                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is adapted from CodesInChaos's extension method. The name is shorter (`NotNull`) and more importantly, restricts the type (`T`) to reference types with `where T : class`.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> NotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : class
    {
        return source.Where(item => item != null);
    }
```

Comment: If you down vote, please comment why. Down voting without cause only discourages contributions. If something is incorrect or incomplete, say so. If you prefer another answer, simply up vote that other answer.

Comment: 1) I didn't downvote, but the restriction to reference types isn't a good idea IMO. It prevents using this method on nullable value types, which is particularly annoying when you want to use this method in another generic method where `T` hasn't been restricted. 2) I'm not too fond of the name change either. With that name I'd expect it to check if `source != null`, not if the elements are not null.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, thank you for the well-reasoned comments. They are appreciated. Unfortunately, C# (at this time) doesn't have a constraint for nullable.

Answer (score 1):

I know i am a bit late to the party but I found a IMO very elegant sollution to this problem. I wrote an extension method to chain onto my LINQ queries:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DiscardNullValues<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> nullable)
    {
        foreach (var item in nullable)
        {
            if (item is not null) yield return item;
        }
    }
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature that have been proposed to the dotnet/runtime issue tracker.

See this comment that proposes a `SelectNotNull` function :
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30381#issuecomment-806396119